# Redirect not working in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

i create a admin bundle. i am using my own logic for check if user logged in. But it is not redirect if user is not logged in. I try to debug code each time when index action called isLoggedIn() function is called via constructor but redirect part in the the is logged in not working.

My controoler code is

```
    <?php

    namespace Nitin\AdminBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Bitcoin\AdminBundle\BitcoinAdminBundle;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

    class AdminController extends Controller {

    public $session;
    public $container;
    public $pageData;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->container = NitinAdminBundle::getContainer();
        $this->session = $this->container->get('session');
        $this->isLoggedIn();
    }

    public function indexAction(Request $request) { //die(''.__LINE__);
        return $this->render('NitinAdminBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }

    public function isLoggedIn() {
        $isLoggedin = $this->session->get('loggedIn', FALSE);

        if (FALSE === $isLoggedin) {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('nitin_admin_login'));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function logoutAction() {
        $this->session->invalidate();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('nitin_admin_login'));
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using __constructor ?

Comment: I know the complexity is terrifying at first, but is _really_ worth it to use symfony's security component.

Comment: @Maerlyn You are right. I am going to use the security component.
But also want to identify why this issue occured.

Comment: @abbiya __constructor is a magic method known as constructor. This function is called each time when the class called. So, if we need to perform any default action each time when any method called we can use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more thing you can do instead of writing `header();`

```
public function isLoggedIn() {
        $isLoggedin = $this->session->get('loggedIn', FALSE);

        if (FALSE === $isLoggedin) {
            $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('nitin_admin_login'))->sendHeaders();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

`sendHeaders()` is a method of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `redirect()` method, it return an instance of `RedirectResponse` and it is used in action methods. (Although, redirect in constructor method isn't best practice) this code can works:

```
protected function isLoggedIn() 
{
    $isLoggedin = $this->session->get('loggedIn', false);

    if (false === $isLoggedin) {
        header('Location: ' . $this->generateUrl('nitin_admin_login'));
        exit;
    }
}
```

As told by @Maerlyn, you must use security component.

Comment: Thanks @aykut you right, I use the security component. but i really want to understood the point. I got it now. Thanks